# How can I add an optional input to a graph in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I basically want to have the option to feed input to the middle of the graph and compute the output going from there. One idea I had is to use `tf.placeholder_with_default` that defaults to a zero tensor. Then I could mix the optional inputs using addition, however addition on a large shape this seems to be a lot of unnecessary computation. Are there better ways of accomplishing that?

```py
input_enabled = tf.placeholder_with_default(tf.constant(1.), [1])

input_shape = [None, in_size]
input = tf.placeholder_with_default(tf.zeros(input_shape), input_shape)
// ...
bottleneck_shape = [None, bottleneck_size]
bottleneck = input_enabled * f(prev_layer) + tf.placeholder_with_default(tf.zeros(bottleneck_shape), bottleneck_shape)
// ...

// Using graph with input at first layer:
sess.run([output], feed_dict={input: x})

// Using graph with input at bottleneck layer:
sess.run([output], feed_dict={bottleneck: b, input_enabled: 0.})
```

Comment: Can you give a more specific overview of your problem? What type of optional input do you want, and to do what?

Comment: A have an autoencoder-like graph and I want to reconstruct a code as input to the bottleneck with the same graph that I use for training.

Comment: Can you give the part of the code you have now with `tf.placeholder_with_default` that you want to change?

Comment: I've added some pseudocode.

Comment: PS, you can feed or fetch any node in TensorFlow graph by fetching/feeding "<name>:0" (print tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def() to get the <name>).

Comment: Very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I understand better thanks to your code.

Basically the schema is:

```
       input       <- you can feed here
         |        
     (encoder)
         |
     bottleneck    <- you can also feed here instead
         |
     (decoder)
         |
       output
```

---

You want two use cases:

1. **train**: feed an image into `input`, compute the output
2. **test**: feed a code into the bottleneck, compute the output

---

You don't need to create a placeholder for `bottleneck`, because `sess.run()` allows you to feed values to **non placeholders** in the Graph:

```py
input_shape = [None, in_size]
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, input_shape)
# ...

bottleneck = f(prev_layer)  # of shape [None, bottleneck_size]
# ...

# Using graph with input at first layer:
sess.run([output], feed_dict={input: x})

# Using graph with input at bottleneck layer:
sess.run([output], feed_dict={bottleneck: b})
```

---

From the documentation of `sess.run()`:

> The optional feed_dict argument allows the caller to override the value of tensors in the graph. Each key in feed_dict can be one of the following types:
>
> If the key is a Tensor, the value may be a Python scalar, string, list, or numpy ndarray that can be converted to the same dtype as that tensor. Additionally, if the key is a placeholder, the shape of the value will be checked for compatibility with the placeholder.